# Tableau live changes replication

Tags: web, dashboard, tableau-api

Suppose i have a dashboard in my local system, and the same dashboard as web service, can we see the live changes in web dashboard if we apply some filter in the local version.

Is there such option?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working off a truly local copy of the workbook, then any changes you make to that workbook will not be reflected in the server based version. Similar to working on a Office file with another copy on SharePoint, changes you make local do not sync to different physical copies of the file.

A couple possible solutions

- You can use the web-based edit functionality of Tableau Server to make changes to a server-hosted version that are seen by all users
- Any edits to the data source are "seen" by Tableau at the time of the data query, so any filtering you apply to the data source will get picked up any time the Tableau desktop/server engine queries the data source. This also applies to any saved data sources you are publishing on Tableau Server (which can be used by workbooks both on Tableau Server and Tableau Desktop). Note that if you are using TWBX files, those are by design self-contained and won't pick up upstream data changes without a manual refresh.

Comment: So, There is nothing like real time to look for changes ? Am i correct ?

Comment: Are you looking for changes to your data? or changes to your workbook? There are lots of features and options. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: There is real time updates, but you have to understand what your model is. If you duplicate a workbook in two different places (a local file and a copy on the server) then changes are not going to take place until you publish the new workbook. The typical workflow for server changes that I use is to open a server published workbook via Tableau Desktop, make my changes, and (once I'm happy with them), republish the workbook to server. Those changes are then live _immediately_.

Comment: @Alex I am looking for changes in workbook. looking for something like this http://help.slides.com/knowledgebase/articles/333924-live-streaming in tableau